# Get textbox value in repeater control when button in same row is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, asprepeater, datarepeater

I have this repeater:

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Caption</th>
                            <th>&nbsp;</th>
                            <th>Update File</th>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Image Width="108px" Height="67px" runat="server" ID="imgDb" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("imageUrl")  %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px;" ID="txtCaption" Text='<%# Eval("caption")  %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             <td><asp:FileUpload ID="fu" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-info" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClick="btn_OnClick" /></td>
                            <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' OnClick="btnDelete_OnClick" Text="Delete" /></td>
                            <td><asp:HiddenField ID="lblC" runat="server" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "id") %>'></asp:HiddenField></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to know how can I get the textbox specifically from the row where the update button is clicked. What logic should I use to get the value I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably do that with handling `Click` event on the button and then getting its parent control. But I would recommend handling command of the repeater instead:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptImages" runat="server"
              OnItemCommand="rptImages_ItemCommand">
```

Remove the handler from the button, but keep the command arg. You may also want to set command name if there are other controls sending commands from within the repeater:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CssClass="btn btn-danger"
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' 
            Text="Delete" />
```

And in the code behind this becomes trivial:

```
protected void rptImages_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = e.Item.FindControl("txtCaption") as TextBox;
}
```